# OS X Lion Apache & PHP not communicating

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

My apologies if this has already been answered - I'm having difficulty finding a solution however.

I'm attempting to make the OSX 10.7.4 Apache, PHP, MySQL leap... I followed this http://echodittolabs.org/blog/2011/09/os-x-107-lion-development-native-apache-php-homebrew-mysql-or-mariadb, which for the most part went flawless (I had a minor hickup with the .plist but that is fixed).

Apache works fine. PHP works fine (thru terminal). I cannot get any PHP file to work via the browser however. I've uncommented `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` as well as included the `IfModule php5_module` piece. I've checked the modules loaded by apache which includes PHP5. Apache error_log provides nothing

Thoughts? (Please don't say use MAMP).

Comment: Is there anything in the Apache error log[s]?

Comment: [warn] mod_bonjur: cannot stat template index file '/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Sites/index.html'.
[warn] mod_bonjur: cannot stat template index file '/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Sites/index.html'.
[notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[notice] Digest: done
[notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: Can you please paste the contents of the `IfModule php5_module` block?

Comment: `<IfModule php5_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line to your `IfModule php5_module` block:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

So it looks like this:

```
<IfModule php5_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
  AddHandler php5-script .php

  <IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```